# Create multiple files with variables using a txt with batch

Tags: batch-file

Sorry for the very simplified version of my question but I'll figure from here.

I have a text file containing one word each line.

```
Peter
Tommy
Mike
```

I have another file containing a text.

```
Hello %VARIABLE%
How are you doing?
```

I'd like to have a batch file that creates one new text file for each line from the first text file and name them accordingly.

Peter.txt:

```
Hello Peter
How are you doing?
```

Tommy.txt:

```
Hello Tommy
How are you doing?
```

Mike.txt:

```
Hello Mike
How are you doing?
```

Here is where I am now.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%x in (file.txt) do set /p nAme=%%x

(
echo Hello %nAme%
echo.
echo How are you doing?
)>%nAme%.txt
```

This (test.bat) only writes the variables on screen, and creates a test.txt file with

```
Hello test

How are you doing?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A FOR command with the /F option is used to read a file.

```
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%G IN ("file.txt") DO (
    echo Hello %%G>"%%G.txt"
    echo How are you doing?>>"%%G.txt"
)
```

Comment: thanks it's great! oh man i was so close :) little mod for me because the real file is a 100+ line ps1 script, is that i only put )>>"%%G.txt" at the end not after every line. thank you!